Icon in smart field eclipse scout
I understand that it is possible to display icons in the selection list when choosing a value, but once the value is selected, the icon disappears from the field.
It seems this field does not support custom HTML, so I cannot inject my image directly.
Here’s how I currently add the icon to the selection list:
row = row.withIconId(Icons.MyIcon);

Additionally, could you help me understand the difference between CodeType and Lookup? I’m not entirely sure I fully grasp their distinct purposes. I assume CodeType is for static set of values and Lookup is dynamic but is it the only difference?
